# Is this possible to document(word) transfer by using SOAP or XML_RPC?

Tags: soap, c#-4.0, soap-client

HI All,

Now i want to send a file(c# Client) to server using SOAP.but i dont know whether it is possible to send file by using SOAP.Does anybody having knowledge about file transfer using SOAP or any other for example XML-RPC, please send me your  thoughts...

Thanks & Regards,
P.SARAVANAN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to read the file (e.g. `file_get_contents()`), encode it in some way (e.g. `base64_encode()`) and pass it to the SOAP or XML-RPC call as a parameter. Example:

```
$soap = new SoapClient('url/to/your.wsdl');
$soap->upload(base64_encode(file_get_contents('file/to/upload')));
```

This, of course, assumes a SOAP server that has a method called `upload` that accepts base64_encoded files.

Comment: I want to send text files from client to Server.So,Is this Possible to send entire text file instead of doing getting contents from the file and then encoding and finally transfer the content...Is this possible to send file as a parameter the to server

Comment: Yes, you can send the entire *contents* of a text file as a parameter to the server. Provided that you do escape XML entities. Your SOAP client library should do that for you automatically.